# How to programmatically change the css background image?

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have a GWT.Label with a background gif.

Depending in states I want to change the color and the image of the label. Color change already works, but I don't know how I could change the background image (while still preserving the gradient):

my.css:

```
/* creates a linear background gradient */
background: #000000;
background: url(myIcon.gif) no-repeat 15px, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
background: url(myIcon.gif) no-repeat 15px, -moz-linear-gradient
background: url(myIcon.gif) no-repeat 15px, -ms-linear-gradient
//etc
```

Changing the color works:

```
getElement().getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor", "green");
//how to change the background image??
```

How can I alter the image property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am facing that situation,instead of changing properties of css  I'l simply change css class

state1

```
lable.addClassName("state1");// in css with image1
```

state2

```
lable.addClassName("state2");//in css with image2
```

Comment: Just to add as reference: this is probably the best approach, but the statement must be: `label.addStyleName("state1");`

Comment: Hmm..true.but my intention is to convey my idea.this is generic .not exactly for gwt.for any language :).